# AHK: swap Key and Shift+Key

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to swap the following inputs:

- { with [
- [ with {

and vica versa.

This code is not doing it (got it from cloudahk.com, I don't quite know how to script for myself):

```
[::{

{::[

]::}

}::]
```

My guess is that the script is executed line by line, so it goes from [ to  { then back to [ again instead of simply swapping.

I would appreciate if the answer could be generalized to other Key + Shift Key variants. (Like swapping + with =).

Answer (score 0):

The script can be forced to terminate with Return, which solves the issue:

```
$[::
    Send {{}
    Return
${::
    Send {[}
    Return
$]::
    Send {}}
    Return
$}::
    Send {]}
    Return
```